# What does "1PieceConcept" mean?

Tags: air-travel, luggage

I received a flight itinerary from a travel agent, and under the "Baggage" column for each segment is listed "1PieceConcept". How should I interpret this?

If it makes a difference, it's for international travel with United/Lufthansa as carriers.

Comment: Related: *[What does “Baggage: 1PC” mean on my flight ticket?](/questions/34652)*

Comment: It means that you are restricted both in the number of bags you can check in (for free), along with the weight of each bag.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid But isn't that the case for pretty much every flight? What is it that "1PieceConcept" is supposed to be telling me, to the extent it's worth taking up an extra column on my itinerary?

Comment: On some flights, they only care about the total weight checked in, irrespective of the number of bags checked in.

Answer (score 3):

Your baggage allowance is usually determined by either 'Piece Concept' or 'Weight Concept'.

A 'Weight Concept' means you will be allowed to check-in X kg of weight. It doesn't matter how many bags there are as long as the weight of all of the bags does not exceed X kg. Some airlines will have an upper limit; like not more than 10 bags.

The 'Piece Concept' on the other hand usually refers to the number of bags that are allowed for check-in. This rules usually defines how many bags you can check-in and the weight and dimension limits of each bag as well. Since you mentioned Lufthansa you can refer to the below description for both cases.

> **Checked baggage – Weight Concept**
>
> First Class    | Business Class | Economy Class
>
> 40 kg (88 lbs) | 30 kg (66 lbs) | 20 kg (44 lbs)
>
> These weight limits apply worldwide except on routes on which the
>   Piece Concept detailed below applies. Maximum baggage item weight 32
>   kg (70 lbs).
>
> **Checked baggage – Piece Concept**
>
> Business Class 2 baggage items of 32 kg (70 lbs) each 
>   Economy Class 2 baggage items of 23 kg (50 lbs) each
>
> Maximum baggage item weight 32 kg (70 lbs).
>
> [LINK](https://www.lufthansa.com/mediapool/pdf/36/media_406536.pdf)

Some practical examples can be:
Weight Concept:

- First class traveler having just 1 32Kg bag.
- Economy traveler having 2 5kg and 1 10Kg bags.

Piece Concept:

- Economy traveler having 1 bag of 23Kg and 1 bag of 23Kg.
- Economy traveler having just 1 bag of 32Kg.

Of course, it is in human nature to maximize the benefit of baggage allowance though. :p

Comment: It might be good to touch on the difference between piece concept and weight concept and where they are used (although I am surprised to see many European and Middle Eastern airlines have switched to piece concept over the last few years).

Comment: Emirates has a good explanation and actually uses both: https://www.emirates.com/us/english/help/faq/490107/weight-and-piece-concept.  Yes, the term 'concept' is rather strange.  A UK English speaker would probably use 'scheme' while a US English speaker would say 'model'.

Comment: Does the "1" in "1PieceConcept" mean anything?

Comment: Yes, it means that 1 piece of luggage (within) the weight and dimensions limits would be free for check-in. The second one won't be free.